# Repository as dependency doesn't affect changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, repository, bitbucket, aws-amplify

My nextjs front-end app on AWS has a back-end dependency in package.json linked it in this way:
`"api-client": "git+https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/api_client_dev.git"`.

When I update my backend repository with changes, locally (npm run dev) everything works, but the app on AWS (with Amplify), when building recognizes an error type about a variable referring to something I haven't done yet.
My front-end doesn't recognize the updated repository.
If I check my repo on bitbucket is updated.
No problems with branches.

I don't understand why. Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in amplify.yml

Adding the script `npm update` on pre-build, force amplify to refresh cached dependencies on node_modules, my dependency included.